# Apollo J Mission CSM- EPS Radiators

Tags: apollo-program

Were the [EPS](http://nassp.sourceforge.net/wiki/Electrical_Power_System_(CSM)) radiators on the J Mission [CSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module)'s upgraded or enlarged to accommodate the increased electrical load imposed by the sim bay equipment?